# Run a part of code every 5 min independently of the other commands

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I want to open, stay open for 6 seconds and close one relay every 5 minutes while the rest code running normally.

For example:

```
GPIO.output(18, 1)
sleep(6)
GPIO.output(18, 0)
sleep(300)
```

But without the rest program stacks in this delay. My Python code  is:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(37, GPIO.OUT)
Hologram = '/home/pi/Hologram/Hologram.mp4'

from subprocess import Popen

firstTimeOpen=0

while True:

        doorIsOpen = GPIO.input(13)

        if doorIsOpen==0 and firstTimeOpen == 0:
                        firstTimeOpen=1
                        GPIO.output(7, 0)
                        GPIO.output(37, 0)
                        sleep(0.5)

        if doorIsOpen==1 and firstTimeOpen == 1:
                GPIO.output(7, 1)
                GPIO.output(37, 1)
                omxp = Popen(['omxplayer' ,Hologram])
                sleep(87)
                GPIO.output(7, 0)
                GPIO.output(37, 0)
                firstTimeOpen=0
                sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: very straight forward problem. you would have found the answer yourself if you go through google search and your code. please take care next time and try yourself first.

Answer (score 4):

Threads offer a convenient way to do this. I normally create a `threading.Thread` subclass, whose `run` method is the code to be run in a separate thread. So you would want something like:

```
class BackgroundRunner(threading.thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            GPIO.output(18, 1)
            sleep(6)
            GPIO.output(18, 0)
            sleep(300)
```

Then, before you start running your main code, use

```
bg_runner = BackgroundRunner()
bg_runner.start()
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the suggested threading methods, you can also use an interrupt using the python signal module. Interrupts are cheaper than threads, which may be more appropriate on your chosen platform.

You can find more examples here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

As an example:

```
import signal, os

def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Signal handler called with signal', signum
    handler.counter += 1

    if not handler.counter % (300 / 6):
        GPIO.output(18, 0)
    else:
        GPIO.output(18, 1)

handler.counter = 0

signal.signal(signal.ITIMER_REAL, handler)
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0, 6)
```

Comment: signal.signal(signal.ITIMER_REAL, handler)
ValueError: signal number out of range

Answer (score 0):

You can put the logic for this in different thread. Will stop freezing your program and won't affect it's workflow.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have earned sufficient reputation, you'll be able to comment on any post. Instead, provide answers that do not require clarification from the asker.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm new on Python and i don't know how can i do that. Can you help me how the code will be formed after that?

Comment: Answer above mine shows that perfectly (holdenweb answer) sorry for not providing code with an answer. I was unable to write it at the moment